# How Can I Reset And Loop This Timer Forever Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a button and a timer inside of it when we click it I was wondering how could I make it so I can set the timer back to 0 and if we click the exit button the timer loops again until it's at 80 and goes back to 0 forever?

I have tried several ways adding a ttimer2 = 0 at the end but it would just loop my timer without me clicking the button any help is appreciated thank you!.

```
        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButton("exit"))
        {
            if (ttimer2 < 80 && flag2)
            {
                ttimer2 += 1;
                UpDown = 2;
                Debug.Log(ttimer);
                transform.Translate(Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
                darkin.SetBool("play", false);
                darkengame.SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            {
                flag2 = true;
                Debug.Log(ttimer);
                darkengame.SetActive(false);
            }



        }
```

Comment: I not understand what you need? Can you explain it better?

Answer (score 1):

you need reset loops index

```
int index = 0;
int maxIndex = 80;
if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButton("exit"))
    {
        if (index >= maxIndex && flag2)
        {
            index = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            index++;
        }



    }
```